# Using bash to pass lines of text file as C arguments

Tags: c, bash, unix

I have a file called entry.txt which has different data entries on each line. What I am trying to do is take all of the entries and pass them to a C program once as a group of arguments. I originally thought to use

```
cat entry.txt >> programFile.c
```

However, that does not seem to work. `programFile.c` is designed to sift through the arguments to make the necessary computations and requires all data sets from `entry.txt` to work correctly. How would I set up the bash command to push the arguments in?

Comment: You need to *compile* your program first and then `cat entry.txt | your_compiled_program`

Comment: @EugeneSh., ...that's passing the file on stdin, not as arguments. And using `cat` is inefficient compared to just directly attaching a handle on the file to stdin, as with `your_compiled_program <entry.txt`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know, but I am not sure the OP is using the correct terminology. Perhaps it needs clarification too

Comment: You need `xargs`: `cat entry.txt | xargs ./yourProgram`

Comment: ...it would be `xargs -d $'\n' your_compiled_program <entry.txt` if what you _really_ want is arguments. That uses GNU extensions; for compatibility with BSD xargs it would instead be `tr '\n' '\d' <entry.txt | xargs -0 your_compiled_program` instead.

Comment: @Pablo, the way you're using xargs there it passes each _word_ as a separate argument, not each line as the OP asked for.

Comment: Show us some snippets of your code, let's see how it sifts through arguments.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, you are right.